# Switching between readonly view and edit view in backbone js

Tags: backbone.js

I am looking for pattern in Backbone js to switch between readonly and edit view. If the trigger for the view is external to the view then no problem I can create the appropriate view ( readonly or edit ) and render it, but in my case the trigger for the edit view will be inside the readonly view.

For example lets say I am displaying a Prescription and by default it is in readonly mode and on hovering a edit icon gets displayed. Onclick of this edit icon the readonly view should now be replaced with edit view. What would be a best approach to achieve this. Below are few options I am considering

1. Have a single PrescriptionView with the edit icon and all the form fields required for the edit mode in it. It will also have the logic to change the view from readonly mode to edit mode based on edit trigger.
2. Have two views PrescriptionReadView and PrescriptionEditView. The ReadView will have the edit icon and onclick replace the readview with editview.

I am inclined towards #2 but not sure how to implement it in a elegant way. Any thoughts on this will be helpful.

Thanks
Zafer

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your life will be considerably less painful, if you separate your pretty view from your edit view, since they are, for all intents and purposes, two *distinct* views of the same data, with different event-handling needs and different behavior.  So, your instincts that lead you towards #2 are *right on the money*.

The cleanest implementation I can think of is to make a container view (say, PrescriptionView) that can handle the mode-swapping events.  The container will own a reference to the currently active prescription view, and will handle the creation of that view, and the cleanup (remove and unbind) of the inactive view.  That keeps all of that logic nice and self-contained.

Comment: You could tunnel the switching logic through a Backbone.Router, the "Edit" button would just activate a route and that route's handler would tell the PrescriptionView to switch to editing mode; the save/cancel actions in the PrescriptionEditView could activate the "show prescription" route.

Comment: @mu - Are there any benefits to that over just having the child view trigger an event which PrescriptionView is listening for?

Comment: @lecstor: It is mostly a matter of where you want your coupling and whether or not you want the edit/show state in the URL; if show/edit is just one little part of the page then you might not want to mess with the URL at all. Starting with the simple routeless approach is fine and make sense but keep the route approach in mind so that you know what tools you have at your disposal.

Comment: Thanks, I have implemented Tess's solution and works great. But it is good to know route based approach as well, will try that too later and see which one works better for me.

Comment: Any idea how to do this with a view at the same level of the DOM, instead of view/edit nested inside the parent?  I'm trying to make Prescription, PrescriptionView, PrescriptionEdit, and have them all point to the same el.  Then I call new Namespace.Views.PrescriptionView({model: this.model, el: this.el}) to set the child's el to this one.  It works at load but then I can't show edit no matter what I do.

Comment: @ZackMorris I use marionette JS and your requirement can be easily done using the regions. Refer https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.region.md . So say your region name is "prescription" and defined in App. To display the PrescriptionView or PrescriptionEdit use "App.prescription.show(new PrescriptionView())" or "App.prescription.show(new PrescriptionEdit())"