# Swap/switch/exchange backbone.js views in place?

Tags: backbone.js, view, switch-statement, exchange-server, swap

I'm implementing view/edit Views in backbone.js for a contacts manager.  The web suggested creating a Contact class with child views called ContactView and ContactEdit.  The problem is, these need to occupy the same el in the DOM, so I can't nest the children inside the parent.  That's because from the outside, I want parent views to only refer to Contact, as if the children were private.  I tried this and it works the first time I render():

```
initialize: function() {
    this.view[0] = new CL.Views.ContactView({model: this.model, el: this.el});
    this.view[1] = new CL.Views.ContactEdit({model: this.model, el: this.el});
},
render: function() {
    this.view[0].render();
    return this;
}
```

But then I can't swap the views.  I tried this.view[0].remove() and everything I can think of, but just can't get the browse and edit views to swap with each other using the same el.

I'm thinking that this means it will be better to have two templates inside one view and just exchange them, which already mostly works.  I'm thinking it's backbone.js doesn't handle inheritance well for views at the same level in the DOM.

I'd prefer to avoid backbone.js extensions, but am up for following whatever patterns they implement.  I'm trying to do this the "right" way because view/edit is such a common pattern for the forms in our app.

P.S. Another way to state this problem is, how does one hide a view and replace it with another view in backbone.js, if there is no parent view enclosing them?

Thanks in advance for any help you can provide.

Comment: This is possible. What's triggering for the views to change?

Comment: They are rows in a contacts list, so when you click one, I want to remove the "view" view and swap it with the edit view.  The problem is, I want to do it in such a way that emulates the functionality of having one view.  That means not nesting another div inside, because it breaks the consistency of the list.

Answer (score 1):

I do not quite understand if you want to have a view for a `Collection` of `Models` or do you want a view for dealing with a single `Model`?

#### If it is a view for a single model,

then you can stick with one view. Just have some events listening for your actions enabling or disabling editing features. (You can do this even by setting up contenteditable="true" on dom elements)

I strongly advise to use some tools like [backbone.marionette](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/) or chaplinjs. They will save you a ton of time.

*Following examples are for Backbone.Marionette*

*example template*

```
<script type="text/template" id="contact-view-template">
  <span data-bind="firstName"></span>
  <span data-bind="lastName"></span>
  <span data-bind="email"></span>
  <a href="#" data-action="edit">
  <a href="#" data-action="save" style="display:none">
</script>
```

*The view code:*

```
ContactView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template:"#contact-view-template",
  events:{
    "click [data-action=edit]":"edit",
    "click [data-action=save]":"save"
  },
  edit:function(){
    this.$("[data-action=edit]").hide();
    this.$("[data-action=save]").show();
    this.$("[data-bind]").attr("contenteditable",true);
  },
  save:function(){
    var value = {};
    _.each(this.$("[data-bind]",function(el){
      value[el.dataset['bind']]= $(el).val() || $(el).text();
    }));
    this.model.set(value);
    // add your validation here
    this.model.save();
  }
});
```

#### If you want to have multiple edit views, than just:

```
ContactListEditView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView:ContactView.extend({
    tagName:"li"
  }),
  itemViewContainer:"ul",
  template:_.template("<h1>ContactList</h1><p>feel free to edit</p><ul></ul>")
});
```

#### If you need 1 edit view and multiple non editable views

(i hope I haven't made any serious errors):

```
ContactEditView = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  template:"#contact-edit-view", // your template & bindings
  events:{
    "click [data-action=save]":"save"
  },
  save:function(){
    var value = {};
    _.each(this.$("[data-bind]",function(el){
      value[el.dataset['bind']]= $(el).val() || $(el).text();
    }));
    this.model.set(value);
    this.model.save();
  }
});


ContactListView = Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView:Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    template:"#contact-view-template",
    events:{
      "click [data-action=edit]":"edit"
    },
    edit:function(){
      this.trigger("edit",this);
    }
  }),
  regions:{
    "edit":"[data-region=edit]"
  },
  initialize:function(){
    this.on("itemview:edit",function(view){
      this.edit.show(new ContactEditView({model:view.model}));
    }.bind(this));
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow awesome! Hope it works... just what I've been looking for. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problems arise from the fact that your parent view shares the same element with the child views. When you render the `ContactView` or `ContactEdit` view, it replaces the DOM element, and when you `remove` a child view, it (by definition) removes the parent view element as well, since they are the same element.

Instead your should compose the parent view so that the child view is rendered **into** the container element. Something like

```
<!-- .contact-container is the parent view el -->
<section class="contact-container">

</section>
```

And then render the child views into the container:

```
initialize: function() {
  //don't give the views an element, let them render into the detached
  //element generated by Backbone
  this.view[0] = new CL.Views.ContactView({model: this.model});
  this.view[1] = new CL.Views.ContactEdit({model: this.model});
  this.currentViewIndex = 0;
},
render: function() {
  //replace the contents with the new view
  this.view[this.currentViewIndex].render();
  this.$el.html(this.view.el);

  return this;
},

swap: function() {
  var i = this.currentViewIndex;
  this.view[i].remove();
  //toggle current view between 0 and 1
  this.currentViewIndex = i === 0 ? 1: 0;
  this.render();
}
```

Then you get

```
<!-- .contact-container is the parent view el -->
<section class="contact-container">
  <div><!-- your child element --></div>
</section>
```

Comment: Ya nesting views that way is consistent with a normal view hierarchy.  I guess my question is if it's possible for a view to inherit from another at the same DOM level.  I've thought about swapping the el's inner htmls and re-delegating the events, but it feels dirty.  I really just need a way for two views to point to the same DOM element, and then be able to swap them and disable the view that's not visible.

Comment: I think you should re-evaluate whether it adds any value to use the same element. You say it's dirty to nest the child view into the parent, but I'd say it's dirtier to reuse the same element, because it goes against the framework. Both ways would achieve precisely the same thing in practice, but yours is difficult and brittle. Suit yourself, though.

Comment: Ya the problem is that if I pass the contact model to the contact view, then I also have to pass it to each child view.  So now I have 3 views pointing to the same model, when really from outside, I want the rest of the page to just see 1 view corresponding to 1 model.  I thought that I could perhaps inherit "edit" from "view" and swap them, but ran into javascript inheritance problems  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14528562/access-parent-class-member-with-javascript-inheritance and the rabbit hole keeps going deeper.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a view that inherits from a base `View` so they can freely operate with the same `Model`.

```
/** Declare base View with specific Model. */
var baseView = Backbone.View.extend({
    model: someModel
});

var contactView = baseView.extend({
   initialize: function() {
        /** Do work specific to contact view. */
   }
});

var editContactView = baseView.extend({
   initialize: function() {
       /** Do work specific to contact edit. */
   }
});

var mainView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {
       /** Initialize two contact views */
       new contactView({ });
       new editContactView({ });
   }
});
```