# Access parent class member with javascript inheritance?

Tags: javascript, class, inheritance, parent, children

I need to extend a base class with additional functionality in javascript.  I'm using backbone.js inheritance as an example here, but it's a general question about extending classes.

http://addyosmani.github.com/backbone-fundamentals/#inheritance-mixins

```
Parent = Backbone.View.extend({
    value: "Parent value",
    func: function(){
        alert('Parent function, ' + this.value);
    }
});

Child = Parent.extend({
    value: "Child value",
    func: function(){
        alert('Child function, ' + this.value);
    },
    test: function(){
        this.constructor.__super__.func.call(this);
        //Parent.prototype.func.call(this)
    }
});

var child = new Child();

child.test();

// prints: Parent function, Child value
// should print: Parent function, Parent value
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GFphK/) sandbox to ease experimentation.

The problem is that extend() seems to work more like interface implementing instead of inheritance.  So Child is really still Parent, but with extra member functions.  The "value" member appears to be virtual, so there is only one instance of it, instead of one per descendent.  In c++ I could say Parent::func() and inside, this->value would be "Parent value".

I have tried the various ._super extensions to backbone.js but they all still suffer from "this" being the wrong context in Parent.  I've also tried _.bindAll() in either/both Child/Parent but it fails for the same reason:

```
initialize: function() {
    _.bindAll(this, 'func');
}
```

1. What's the cleanest way to have "this" be the proper context in the Parent in javascript, or at least simulate that functionality with a minimum of code?
2. Do I need to create a "parent" member in Child and instantiate it to create "value" members for each descendent?

Comment: in `test()`, try this: `Parent.prototype.func.call(this)` -- what do you get?

Comment: Unfortunately no, I just tried it, but thanks for pointing out how to refer to it like c++ Parent::func(), I think that will be useful down the road for me.  I updated it with a jsfiddle sandbox so people can play around with it.